# Need help resolving Arduino Code error [-Woverflow] in gimbal code. I am not sure how to resolve or if to disable yaw

Tags: c++, c, arduino, robotics, gyroscope

This code is not mine, but found on [How To Mechatronics](https://howtomechatronics.com/projects/diy-arduino-gimbal-self-stabilizing-platform/).

I am working on an Arduino gimbal and am using this code. It brings up an error, which I will paste at the bottom.

I searched this sort of error and it seems it is because it has an output that is negative but is not defined to come out as negative or may be too large.

I am not quite sure what to change or how to change this in order to function. I also have a problem with the yaw motor, which I believe may be fried because my brother connected it to a 12 V battery and it is only supposed to be 5 V.

I am sure I can disable the yaw (although not sure if this would solve the other issue), but I don't know which lines to code out in order to do so.

```
/*
  DIY Gimbal - MPU6050 Arduino Tutorial
  by Dejan, www.HowToMechatronics.com
  Code based on the MPU6050_DMP6 example from the i2cdevlib library by Jeff Rowberg:
  https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib
*/
// I2Cdev and MPU6050 must be installed as libraries, or else the .cpp/.h files
// for both classes must be in the include path of your project
#include "I2Cdev.h"

#include "MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h"
//#include "MPU6050.h" // not necessary if using MotionApps include file

// Arduino Wire library is required if I2Cdev I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE implementation
// is used in I2Cdev.h
#if I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE
#include "Wire.h"
#endif
#include <Servo.h>
// class default I2C address is 0x68
// specific I2C addresses may be passed as a parameter here
// AD0 low = 0x68 (default for SparkFun breakout and InvenSense evaluation board)
// AD0 high = 0x69
MPU6050 mpu;
//MPU6050 mpu(0x69); // <-- use for AD0 high

// Define the 3 servo motors
Servo servo0;
Servo servo1;
Servo servo2;
float correct;
int j = 0;

#define OUTPUT_READABLE_YAWPITCHROLL

#define INTERRUPT_PIN 2  // use pin 2 on Arduino Uno & most boards

bool blinkState = false;

// MPU control/status vars
bool dmpReady = false;  // set true if DMP init was successful
uint8_t mpuIntStatus;   // holds actual interrupt status byte from MPU
uint8_t devStatus;      // return status after each device operation (0 = success, !0 = error)
uint16_t packetSize;    // expected DMP packet size (default is 42 bytes)
uint16_t fifoCount;     // count of all bytes currently in FIFO
uint8_t fifoBuffer[64]; // FIFO storage buffer

// orientation/motion vars
Quaternion q;           // [w, x, y, z]         quaternion container
VectorInt16 aa;         // [x, y, z]            accel sensor measurements
VectorInt16 aaReal;     // [x, y, z]            gravity-free accel sensor measurements
VectorInt16 aaWorld;    // [x, y, z]            world-frame accel sensor measurements
VectorFloat gravity;    // [x, y, z]            gravity vector
float euler[3];         // [psi, theta, phi]    Euler angle container
float ypr[3];           // [yaw, pitch, roll]   yaw/pitch/roll container and gravity vector

// packet structure for InvenSense teapot demo
uint8_t teapotPacket[14] = { '$', 0x02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x00, 0x00, '\r', '\n' };



// ================================================================
// ===               INTERRUPT DETECTION ROUTINE                ===
// ================================================================

volatile bool mpuInterrupt = false;     // indicates whether MPU interrupt pin has gone high
void dmpDataReady() {
  mpuInterrupt = true;
}

// ================================================================
// ===                      INITIAL SETUP                       ===
// ================================================================

void setup() {
  // join I2C bus (I2Cdev library doesn't do this automatically)
#if I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.setClock(400000); // 400kHz I2C clock. Comment this line if having compilation difficulties
#elif I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_BUILTIN_FASTWIRE
  Fastwire::setup(400, true);
#endif

  // initialize serial communication
  // (115200 chosen because it is required for Teapot Demo output, but it's
  // really up to you depending on your project)
  Serial.begin(38400);
  while (!Serial); // wait for Leonardo enumeration, others continue immediately

  // initialize device
  //Serial.println(F("Initializing I2C devices..."));
  mpu.initialize();
  pinMode(INTERRUPT_PIN, INPUT);
  devStatus = mpu.dmpInitialize();
  // supply your own gyro offsets here, scaled for min sensitivity
  mpu.setXGyroOffset(17);
  mpu.setYGyroOffset(-69);
  mpu.setZGyroOffset(27);
  mpu.setZAccelOffset(1551); // 1688 factory default for my test chip

  // make sure it worked (returns 0 if so)
  if (devStatus == 0) {
    // turn on the DMP, now that it's ready
    // Serial.println(F("Enabling DMP..."));
    mpu.CalibrateAccel(6);
    mpu.CalibrateGyro(6);
    mpu.PrintActiveOffsets();
    mpu.setDMPEnabled(true);

    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(INTERRUPT_PIN), dmpDataReady, RISING);
    mpuIntStatus = mpu.getIntStatus();

    // set our DMP Ready flag so the main loop() function knows it's okay to use it
    //Serial.println(F("DMP ready! Waiting for first interrupt..."));
    dmpReady = true;

    // get expected DMP packet size for later comparison
    packetSize = mpu.dmpGetFIFOPacketSize();
  } else {
    // ERROR!
    // 1 = initial memory load failed
    // 2 = DMP configuration updates failed
    // (if it's going to break, usually the code will be 1)
    // Serial.print(F("DMP Initialization failed (code "));
    //Serial.print(devStatus);
    //Serial.println(F(")"));
  }

  // Define the pins to which the 3 servo motors are connected
  servo0.attach(10);
  servo1.attach(9);
  servo2.attach(8);
}
// ================================================================
// ===                    MAIN PROGRAM LOOP                     ===
// ================================================================

void loop() {
  // if programming failed, don't try to do anything
  if (!dmpReady) return;

  // wait for MPU interrupt or extra packet(s) available
  while (!mpuInterrupt && fifoCount < packetSize) {
    if (mpuInterrupt && fifoCount < packetSize) {
      // try to get out of the infinite loop
      fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();
    }
  }

  // reset interrupt flag and get INT_STATUS byte
  mpuInterrupt = false;
  mpuIntStatus = mpu.getIntStatus();

  // get current FIFO count
  fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();

  // check for overflow (this should never happen unless our code is too inefficient)
  if ((mpuIntStatus & _BV(MPU6050_INTERRUPT_FIFO_OFLOW_BIT)) || fifoCount >= 1024) {
    // reset so we can continue cleanly
    mpu.resetFIFO();
    fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();
    Serial.println(F("FIFO overflow!"));

    // otherwise, check for DMP data ready interrupt (this should happen frequently)
  } else if (mpuIntStatus & _BV(MPU6050_INTERRUPT_DMP_INT_BIT)) {
    // wait for correct available data length, should be a VERY short wait
    while (fifoCount < packetSize) fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();

    // read a packet from FIFO
    mpu.getFIFOBytes(fifoBuffer, packetSize);

    // track FIFO count here in case there is > 1 packet available
    // (this lets us immediately read more without waiting for an interrupt)
    fifoCount -= packetSize;

    // Get Yaw, Pitch and Roll values
#ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_YAWPITCHROLL
    mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
    mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
    mpu.dmpGetYawPitchRoll(ypr, &q, &gravity);

    // Yaw, Pitch, Roll values - Radians to degrees
    ypr[0] = ypr[0] * 180 / M_PI;
    ypr[1] = ypr[1] * 180 / M_PI;
    ypr[2] = ypr[2] * 180 / M_PI;
    
    // Skip 300 readings (self-calibration process)
    if (j <= 300) {
      correct = ypr[0]; // Yaw starts at random value, so we capture last value after 300 readings
      j++;
    }
    // After 300 readings
    else {
      ypr[0] = ypr[0] - correct; // Set the Yaw to 0 deg - subtract  the last random Yaw value from the currrent value to make the Yaw 0 degrees
      // Map the values of the MPU6050 sensor from -90 to 90 to values suatable for the servo control from 0 to 180
      int servo0Value = map(ypr[0], -90, 90, 0, 180);
      int servo1Value = map(ypr[1], -90, 90, 0, 180);
      int servo2Value = map(ypr[2], -90, 90, 180, 0);
      
      // Control the servos according to the MPU6050 orientation
      servo0.write(servo0Value);
      servo1.write(servo1Value);
      servo2.write(servo2Value);
    }
#endif
  }
}
```

[image]

See image for error code. There is only one exit condition, so I believe this is the only issue.

the arrow in the error code (~~^~~~~~~) points at (2*16384);

Comment: On Arduino, `int` is 16-bit. `2*16384` is too large to fit in a 16-bit signed int. I have no idea why authors of this library didn't use the constant 32768 there, perhaps you want to ask them?

Comment: Please do not attach screenshots - rather copy-paste the error you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a warning for an int overflow in the MPU6050 library code, not in your code.

On Github, an [issue](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/issues/380) was raised about this some time ago, which also has the fix in the same posting.

Another solution suggested in the [comments there](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/issues/380#issuecomment-408547936) to get rid of this warning is to simply change the "16384" to "16384L" in the library code.

Note that i2cdevlib has 247 open issues; I don't think the owner/maintainer will fix this particular problem any time soon.

Comment: Do you believe that the open issues will affect the code? If so are there other working libraries that could be included and edited into the current code (replace current libraries in code)?

Comment: There may be other problems in the part of the library you use, but I wouldn't worry too much about that: what works, works. The patch suggested should take care of the warning you get. I don't know about other libraries that can do what you want, but that is easily googled. Don't forget to accept the answer (if you accept it, that is).